# Are questions about guns attached to aircraft on topic?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

This [question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/16312/what-is-the-highest-muzzle-velocity-of-a-gun-on-any-fighter-aircraft) asks what aircraft gun has the highest muzzle velocity.  I'm not sure if it's on topic because it specifically mentions airplanes or if it's off topic because it's really, technically, about guns.

So I thought I'd just ask the community what it thought...  It certainly feels like it's close to "the line" as far as defining what this site is about.

Answer (score 2):

I think whether or not these borderline questions are on topic has everything to do with the answers they get. The question is clearly related to aviation, so I see no reason to prematurely close it. If we start getting lots of questions about a particular subject which is related to aviation, but consistently not getting good answers, then we can start to consider them off-topic.